# Function with generic parameter java

Tags: java, generics

I have a **tree of objects T**, declared as

```
 public class Tree<T> {

    private Node<T> root;

    public Tree(T rootData) {
        root = new Node<T>();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }

    public static class Node<T> {
        private T data;
        private Node<T> parent;
        private List<Node<T>> children;
    }
}
```

and want to add a function `keepBranch`, wich reduces the tree to one of its branch.

But I need `keepBranch` to **take an object T as a parameter**, to select the branch.
Something like

```
public void keepBranch(<T> param) {

        for (Node<T> node : this.root.children) {
            if (param.equals(node.data)) {
                this.root = node;
            }
        }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: `<T>` is used to define a type variable in a certain context. But once defined, you can use `T` as you would use any other class name. (Syntactically, that is. You can't do everything you could do with a concrete class name.)

Comment: You already have an example for the correct usage in your constructor `public Tree(T rootData)`, so I wonder why you've thought that you need to use `<T>`.

Comment: @Tom Took the tree code from another thread, as I'm beginning with generics and trying to understand it. But yeah you're right I should have noticed!

Comment: `data` in our code should be unique for whole tree. if it isn't so you can get wrong branch by data comparison.

Comment: @VladBochenin You're right, I will be carefull when using it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `T param` instead of `<T> param` :

```
public void keepBranch(T param) {

        for (Node<T> node : this.root.children) {
            if (param.equals(node.data)) {
                this.root = node;
            }
        }
}
```

### EDIT

As said in comments, it should be `param.equals(node.data)` instead of `node == param`

Documentation : [Lesson: Generics (Updated)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: `node == param` is comparing `Node<T> == T`. is it correct?

Comment: @jackjay no, it's not. It has to be compared to ``node.data``.

Comment: Well I just took this comparison for the example, I can edit it if it bothers you though.

Comment: @jackjay No, I just thought of passing a parameter of type T, to compare it to the node data. Should I pass a Node<T> type instead?

Answer (score 4):

Change the parameter type to `T`. But your comparison is wrong, you compare a value to a node. Change is so that the node's value is being compared to `param`:

```
public void keepBranch(T param) {
    for (Node<T> node : this.root.children) {
        if (param.equals(node.data)) {
            this.root = node;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP maybe wants to compare by reference. For example some nodes could be equals but placed on different places in tree

Comment: @VladBochenin It isn't the reference comparison that is the biggest problem, it's comparing a `Node` instance (`node`) to something that is definitely not a `Node` instance (`param`).